# How do I export my rendered Animation images to disk/save them after rendering?

Tags: rendering, animation

I am using Windows 10 and Blender 2.81 beta.

[image]

[image]

So here I have set file destinations for both cache AND the output on the disk, as you can see.

And this is the option I am selecting to Render the animation out, which it does without issue for 250 frames.

[image]

When I navigate to it on my PC, the folder ends up empty at the end. What step have I missed here?

Render looks something like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That just sets the default path for new blend files.

You need to set it up in the *Output Properties Panel*

[image]